# Al seleccionar el select la primera vez el valor es undefine - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

****tengo un inconveniente puntual , envio solo el código que tengo problemas, al seleccionar un valor en el select no carga queda undefine en mi input me toca volver a seleccionar otro valor en el select para que aparezca el valor, necesito que el valor que seleccione en el select me cargue de una y no tener que seleccionar dos veces un valor para que funcione .****

```js
  const setSelect = (value) => {
  if (initialeRow.nombre >= 1) {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
      setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre - 1 });
      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }
  }
}
      
      
      const handleInput_division = (event) => {
      
       const { name, value } = event.target;
  setSelect(value)
  setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });
  setInitialRow({ nombre: event.target.value });
     
    };


      return (
           
        <select  onChange={handleInput_division} name='' >
                <option value='9'>9</option>
               <option value='10'>10</option>  
               <option value='11'>10</option>  
                 
              </select>
              
      //input
      {rows.map((e, index) => (
            <Row
              nombre={e.nombre}
              index={index}
              onChange={(index, value) => handleOnChange(index, value)}
              key={index}
            />
    )
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, no tiendo que quieres lograr, solo entendi que quieres agregar una función al select que haga algo cuando se dispare el onChange, pero no se que quieres hacer después, edita tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: lo que en si necesito es que llame otra funcion dentro del onchange sin mover lo que ya hay..

Comment: Puedes crear otra función que haga lo que necesitas y dentro de esa funcion tambien declaras el setSelect

Comment: esta es la funcion setselect : const setSelect = (value) => {
    if (initialeRow.nombre >= 1) {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray ) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }
    if (isArray ) {
      setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre - 1 });
      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }
   
  }  , como hago para agregar las lineas de codigo que menciono en la pregunta?

Comment: Esa repuesta va en el cuerpo de la pregunta, cualquier duda que tengas, escribela en el cuerpo de la pregunta, ten en cuenta que entre más información compartas, más personas podran ayudarte y mejor calidad de repuestas obtendras, a demas, me hes dificil leer tu repuesta sin un identado, entonces tambien ten en cuenta que entre más facil des la informacion, mas personas se animaran a responder tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

no esto muy seguro de lo que intentas hacer, a lo que entiendo podrias hacer algo asi:

```
const setSelect = (value) => {
  if (initialeRow.nombre >= 1) {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
      setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre - 1 });
      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }
  }
}

const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setSelect(value)
  setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });
  setInitialRow({ nombre: event.target.value });
}

return(
  <select  onChange={handleChange} name='numberIni3' >
    <option value="5">5</option>  
  </select>
)
```

Comment: encontre el problema del codigo que me subio pero no se como solucionarlo, lo que pasa es que el select cuando selecciono por primera vez el valor no lo carga queda undefine y toca seleccionar otro valor y hay si lo carga...

Comment: reformule la pregunta con un codigo mas legible por si me puede ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494116/me-toca-seleccionar-dos-veces-dos-valores-en-el-select-para-que-me-reconozca-el