# me toca seleccionar dos veces dos valores en el select para que me reconozca el primer valor que seleccione - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Cuando selecciono cualquier valor en mi select por ejemplo "5" debe cargarme un boton y al darle clic a ese boton debe aparecerme en un input el valor que sigue que en este ejemplo seria "6", el problema que tengo es que al seleccionar un valor por ejemplo "5" en el select  no me esta cargando el boton y me toca seleccionar otro valor y hay si me carga el boton y al darle clic hay si me carga en el input el valor de "6".

Mi algoritmo lo unico que hace es que pide un valor x y al ingresarlo y darle al boton me genera un select con la cantidad de numeros que haya colocado en input, luego selecciono un valor del select y debería cargarme un boton y al darle clic debe cargarme un input con el numero que sigue.

El problema que tengo es que al seleccionar un valor en el select el sistema me lo reconoce como undefine y me toca seleccionar otra valor y hay si me hace el proceso.

https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-fire-j4bbx?file=/src/App.js:0-6043

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

//input dinamico

import Row from "./Row2";

let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: []
};

function Esquema_torneo(props) {
  //input dinamico

  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [initialeRow, setInitialRow] = useState({ nombre: "" });
  const updateCount = (event) => {
    setInitialRow({ nombre: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleOnChange = (index, value) => {
    const copy = rows.map((e, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        e.nombre = value;
      }
      return e;
    });
    setRows([...copy]);
  };
/********************************************/

  const [number, setNumber] = useState();
  const [modocuatro, setModoCuatro] = useState(null);
  const [input_multi, setInput_multi] = useState();


  const handleClick_cuatro = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setModoCuatro(true);
  };



  const handleInput_select = (event) => {

      const { name, value } = event.target;
    
    setSelect(value)
    
    setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });
    setInitialRow({ nombre: event.target.value });


  };

  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);
  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);


  const getArray = (value) => {
    let arr = [];
    {
      let reco = Math.round(numberIni - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco);

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key) => {
          arr.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key + 1));
        });
    }
    return arr;
  };

  const setSelect = (value) => {
    
    
    if (initialeRow.nombre >= 1) {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray ) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }
    if (isArray ) {
      setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre * 1 + 1 }) ;
      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }

  }
  };


  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value);    
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div class="row">
         
     
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <h6>1. INGRESE NUMERO</h6>
              <div class="input-group ">
                <input
                  type="number"
                  name="numberIni"
                  placeholder="0"
                  class="form-control"
                  value={input_multi}
                  onChange={(event) => setInput_multi(event.target.value)}
                 
                />
                <br />
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
                  <i class="far fa-save"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
         

         
        </div>
      </form>
      <br />
  
  
      <br /> <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          {numberIni && (
            <div>
             
              <label>
                <font size="2">
                  MI SELECT :&nbsp;{" "}
                </font>
              </label>
              <select
              onChange={handleInput_select}
             
               
              >
                <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
                  .fill(1)
                  .map((value, key) => {
                    return <option value={key + 1}>{key + 1} Equipos</option>;
                  })}
              </select>
             

              


              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>
                    <font size="2">
                      {" "}
                      &nbsp;{" "}
                      {rows.map((e, index) => (
                        <button
                          className="btn btn-primary"
                          onClick={handleClick_cuatro}
                        >
                          GENERAR NUMERO SIGUIENTE DE SELECT EN INPUT
                        </button>
                      ))}{" "}
                    </font>{" "}
                  </label>
                </div>

                {modocuatro ? (
                  <div class="col-sm-6" style={{ top: "12px" }}>
                    <br />
                    {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
                      .fill(1)
                      .map((value, key2) => {
                        return (
                          <div>
                            {arraySelect[key2] && (
                              <>
                                <label>
                                  <font size="2">
                                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <label>
                                        <font size="2">
                                          {" "}
                                          &nbsp;{" "}
                                          {rows.map((e, index) => (
                                            <Row
                                              nombre={e.nombre}
                                              index={index}
                                              onChange={(index, value) =>
                                                handleOnChange(index, value)
                                              }
                                              key={index}
                                            />
                                          ))}{" "}
                                        </font>{" "}
                                      </label>
                                    </div>
                                  </font>{" "}
                                </label>
                                <br /> <br />
                              </>
                            )}
                          </div>
                        );
                      })}
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <></>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default Esquema_torneo;
```

//rows.js

```js
const Row = (props) => {
    const { onChange, onRemove, nombre, index } = props;
    console.log(props);
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Ubicados en la
</label>
        <input
        disabled
          value={nombre  * 1 + 1 +  " Posición"}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(index, e.target.value)} 
          placeholder="Decrementar"
        />
        
      </div>
    );
  };
  export default Row;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al leer el código noté lo siguiente:

```js
  const handleInput_select = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setSelect(value);

    setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });
    setInitialRow({ nombre: event.target.value });
  };

  const setSelect = (value) => {
    if (initialeRow.nombre >= 1) {
      let isArray = getArray(value);
      if (isArray) {
        setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
      }
      if (isArray) {
        setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre * 1 + 1 });
        setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
      }
    }
  };
```

Tu función `handleInput` invoca a `setSelect` en línea 3, para así poder crear el input que comentas, luego en `setSelect` en línea 1, haces una validación si el valor de `initialeRow` ya existe. PERO si te fijas ese valor es creado un poco después en el `handleInput` en la línea 5.

Por esta razón ocurre en la 2da modificación. Por esto, podrías modificar la función `setSelect` de dos maneras distintas:

- Que no haga la validación
- Que valide el `value` que recibe (que es el mismo value que va a tener el initaleRow cuando termine de ejecutarse la función `handleInput`
- también deberías usar el value como referencia si quieres para el `setRows` y el `setInitialRow`

```js
  const setSelect = (value) => {
    debugger;
      let isArray = getArray(value);
      if (isArray) {
        console.log([...arraySelect, isArray])
        setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
      }
      if (isArray) {
        setInitialRow({ nombre: value });
        setRows([...rows, { nombre: value}]);
      }
  };
```

Si modificas tu codigo con este select debería funcionar.

Comment: tengo una pregunta necesito que  setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);  necesito cambiarle el valor de initialeRow como lo hago ?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta :thinking_face:

Comment: osea initialeRow inicia con un valor x siempre , como hago para alterarlo y que comience desde otro valor.

Comment: Para eso, en tu código tienes una parte que dice: ```const [initialeRow, setInitialRow] = useState({ nombre: "" }); ```, allí puedes establecer el valor inicial. Ahora, para alterarlo, puedes hacer ```setInitialRow({ nombre: 'NuevoValor' })```

Comment: listo muchas gracias, me sirvió la solución